# OneToMany relationship gets lost on partial update of an object

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

i have a problem with updating my objects.
My Object has these attributes (and more, but the problem is the same)

```
public String testString;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
public List<Mail> mails;
```

Lets assume i have an Instance of this type where testString is NULL and there is one email in the mails list. This object gets persistet in the database just fine.

Now try to update WITHOUT giving it a list of mails.

```
final Map<String, String> values1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
values1.put("id", user.getId().toString());

Form<User> userForm1 = Form.form(User.class);
userForm1 = userForm1.bind(values1).get().update()
```

(i removed the unnecessary  code to check stuff, and yes this is kind of an empty update, but the same happens when i include other fields)
After this update the list of mails is empty.... But other simple fields still have their values. SO i assume i'm doing it right, and play sees a null field in the "new" object, and not overwrites the old value with null, just the fields that are set in the updateobject.

But this does not work on OneToMany relationships. Is this intended or a Bug?
If it is intended, how should i update an object with such relationships?

this is a system.out.println of the original object

```
User [username=Timmeey, testString=null, jobs=[], mails=[timmeey@xxx.xxx, isMainMail: true, id: 1], getCreated()=1401647537627, getModified()=1401647537627, getId()=1]
```

This is from the form

```
User [username=null, testString=null, jobs=[], mails=[], getCreated()=null, getModified()=null, getId()=1]
```

And this is the object after the update

```
User [username=Timmeey, testString=null, jobs=[], mails=[], getCreated()=1401647537627, getModified()=1401647537727, getId()=1]
```

As we can see, play did not overwrite all null fields, because the username is still there, just the mail field was overwritten

Of course i know i could do it manually and iterate over the fieleds and check whether they are null and then set the field that should get updated myself, but i cannot imagine this should be the way to go.

Thank you

TL;DR
Play/Ebean recognizes null values while updating an already saved object. So it will perform an partial-update, only overwriting fields with non-null values. This works for simple things, like String username. But when it comes to relationships like @OneToMany it fails, and always overwrites the stored value with the value from the new object, EVEN when it is null. 
What i want is, that also relationship fields are treated like normal fields, and when the field is null, the field on the old object should not be overwritten

The whole model class

```
package models;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.naming.directory.InvalidAttributeValueException;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.PrePersist;
import javax.persistence.PreUpdate;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.Null;

import com.avaje.ebean.Ebean;

import controllers.SettingsController;
import exceptions.InputValidationException;
import exceptions.NotYetInitializedException;
import play.Logger;
import play.data.validation.ValidationError;

@Entity
@Table(name = "userTable")
@DiscriminatorValue("aUser")
// User may be a reserved keyword in some sql databases
public class User extends AbstractSuperModel {
final static Logger.ALogger logger = Logger.of(User.class);
final private static String usernameRegexPattern = "[\\w_-]{3,}";

// This prevents binding of this value from forms
@Null
@javax.persistence.Column(unique = true)
private String username; // Must not be set by forms, only by controllers

// @OneToMany
// private Set<Ticket> responsibleForTickets;
// @ManyToMany
// private Set<Ticket> subscribedTickets;
// @OneToMany
// private Set<Ticket> reportedTickets;
// //public String secondaryEmails;

private String testString;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<Job> jobs;

@Null
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
public List<Mail> mails;

public User(String username) throws InputValidationException {
    logger.info("Adding a new User: " + username);
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(usernameRegexPattern);
    if (!regex.matcher(username).matches()) {
        logger.error(username
                + " is not a valid username. In case you not just tried to troll the system, consider this as a serious Error and contact the maintainer (Timmeey@xxx.xxx (2014)");
        throw new InputValidationException(username
                + " is not a valid username");

    }

    this.setUsername(username);
    Mail mail = new Mail();
    mail.setMailAddr(username + "@xxx.xxx");
    mail.setIsMainMail(true);
    this.addMail(mail);

}

public void addMail(Mail mail) {
    this.getMails().add(mail);
}

public Mail getMainMail() {
    for (Mail mail : this.getMails()) {
        if (mail != null && mail.getIsMainMail()) {
            return mail;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Removes a Mail from the User.
 * 
 * @param mail
 *            The mail that should get removed
 */
public void removeMail(Mail mail) {
    for (Iterator<Mail> iterator = this.getMails().iterator(); iterator
            .hasNext();) {
        Mail tmpMail = iterator.next();
        if (tmpMail.getMailAddr().equalsIgnoreCase(mail.getMailAddr())) {
            tmpMail.delete();
            return;
        }

    }
}

public void addJob(Job job) {
    this.jobs.add(job);
    this.update();
}

public void removeJob(Job job) {
    this.getJobs().remove(job);
    this.update();
}

public static Finder<Long, User> find = new Finder<Long, User>(Long.class,
        User.class);



public static List<User> findAll() {
    return User.find.all();
}

public static User findById(final Long id) {
    return User.find.byId(id);
}

public static User findByMail(final String address) {
    final Mail mail = Mail.findByAddr(address);
    if (mail != null) {
        return mail.getUser();
    }
    return null;
}

public static User findByName(final String username) {
    User resultUser = null;
    resultUser = User.find.where().eq("username", username).findUnique();
    return resultUser;
}

public static boolean isKnownUser(final String username) {
    return findByName(username) != null;
}

/**
 * Will be executed before a User is saved into the Database.
 */
@PreUpdate
public void processMailAddresses() {
}

public List<ValidationError> validate() {
    List<ValidationError> errors = new ArrayList<ValidationError>();
    if (errors.size() != 0) {
        return errors;
    }
    return null;
}

public List<Job> getJobs() {
    return this.jobs;
}

public List<Mail> getMails() {
    if (this.mails == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return this.mails;
}

public String getTestString() {
    return this.testString;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return this.username;
}

public void setJobs(final List<Job> jobs) {
    this.jobs = jobs;
}

public void setMails(final List<Mail> mails) {
    this.mails = mails;
}

public void setTestString(final String testString) {
    this.testString = testString;
}

public void setUsername(final String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public boolean hasJob(Job job) {
    if (getJobs() == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return this.getJobs().contains(job);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    final List<String> jobs = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Job job : this.getJobs()) {
        jobs.add(job.getJobName());
    }

    final List<String> mails = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (final Mail mail : this.getMails()) {
        mails.add(mail.getMailAddr() + ", isMainMail: "
                + mail.getIsMainMail() + ", id: " + mail.getId());
    }

    return String
            .format("User [username=%s, testString=%s, jobs=%s, mails=%s, getCreated()=%s, getModified()=%s, getId()=%s]",
                    this.username, this.testString, jobs, mails,
                    this.getCreated(), this.getModified(), this.getId());
}


}
```

And the Mail class

```
package models;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.validation.constraints.Null;

import play.Logger;
import play.Logger.ALogger;
import play.data.validation.Constraints.Email;
import play.data.validation.Constraints.Required;
import play.data.validation.ValidationError;

/**
 * Just a container for Emails. Because Play! cannot store List<String> for the
 * Email-Addresses
 * 
 * @author timmeey
 * 
 */
@Entity
public class Mail extends AbstractSuperModel {
private static final ALogger logger = Logger.of(Mail.class);

public static Mail findByAddr(final String address) {
    Mail mail = null;
    mail = find.where().eq("mailAddr", address).findUnique();
    return mail;

}

@Required
@Email
@javax.persistence.Column(unique = true)
private String mailAddr;

@Null
@ManyToOne
private User user;

@Null
Boolean isMainMail;

public static Finder<Long, Mail> find = new Finder<Long, Mail>(Long.class,
        Mail.class);

public static Mail findById(final Long id) {
    if (id == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return find.byId(id);
}

public static List<Mail> findAll() {
    return find.all();
}

public String getMailAddr() {
    return this.mailAddr;
}

public User getUser() {
    return this.user;
}

public void setMailAddr(final String mailAddr) {
    this.mailAddr = mailAddr;
}

public void setUser(final User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String
            .format("Mail [id=%s, mailAddr=%s, user=%s, getCreated()=%s, getModified()=%s, getId()=%s]",
                    this.id, this.mailAddr, this.user.getUsername(),
                    this.getCreated(), this.getModified(), this.getId());
}

public Boolean getIsMainMail() {
    return isMainMail;
}

public void setIsMainMail(Boolean isMainMail) {
    this.isMainMail = isMainMail;
}

public List<ValidationError> validate() {
    List<ValidationError> errors = new ArrayList<ValidationError>();

    if (find.where().eq("mailAddr", this.mailAddr).findRowCount() > 0) {
        errors.add(new ValidationError(mailAddr, "Mailaddress already used"));
    }
    if (errors.size() != 0) {
        return errors;
    }
    return null;

}

}
```

Comment: Can you show us your whole model class?

Comment: Sure, but i don't know how the whole modles could help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem actually is not in your ORM annotations. It is a lack of support from play for rendering different objects within a form and getting information back. I assume that you want to give an object to a form, render the result in a view, then the user types some changes to the other fields apart from the mails, and then you update the changed information. The form itself uses automatically the getters and setters to generate fields and then extract information from request. In your case there is no proper mapping for your list of mails and the HTML fields. What I mean is that if you have a field `String name;` with getters and setters, the form will automatically create fields to be filled matching the name conventions and then later will bind information from this fields to your User object using a setter, which has to be named `setName(String name)`. But when the information is of a specific type different from the basis types or `String`, like `Mail`, there is no proper way that the form will create a field in the HTML for it. So you basically need some manual work. You have to whether save your E-mails in the java code and later add them to the user, who has to be updated, if you are not willing to change them or give them in a proper form like String to the view using the form, and then later extract the information out of the fields generated in the view using a `DynamicForm`.

The view itself is a plain HTML in end effect, no matter if you use the render methods with a form parameter. So there is no direct mapping between your java objects and the HTML files. The `bind` method will simply go through all of the id's of the input fields of the request and will try to find matching setters (so the name of the setters is critical). But when you use more specific objects, you need to do this job manually.

Comment: Thank you Ivaylo, but this is not my problem. I posted the Junit test code. I could easily fill a user form with the values for the mails, lets say in a hidden field. and play would be able to map them correctly. The problem is just that play MUST understand it should skip NULL fields on updates and overwrite only things that are set/not NULL. 
As you can see, in my constructed form i did not include the username field, but play still knew it should not overwrite the username with null. All i want is the same behaviour for complex relationships.